# ProxyCommand use for multiple hops and prompt authentication

Tags: ssh

How can I rewrite the following command with `ProxyCommand`?

```
ssh -l username1 -t jumphost1 \
ssh -l username2 -t jumphost2 \
ssh -l username3 -t jumphost3 \
ssh -l username4    server
```

This doesn't work

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="\
ssh -l username1 -t jumphost1  \
ssh -l username2 -t jumphost2  \
ssh -l username3 -t jumphost3" \
    -l username4    server

username1@jumphost1's password:
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I'm aware of its use with `nc`, but I'm searching for way to use it with 3+ hops, and also use this option with `scp`. I checked `ssh_config` man page, but the information is quite scarce, for me at least.

**EDIT**

I tried using `ProxyCommand` nested in another `ProxyCommand` as suggested below but I always get something along the following lines

```
debug3: ssh_init_stdio_forwarding: 192.17.2.2:2222
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd 192.17.2.2:2222
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

Fortunately, since `7.3` `-J` or `ProxyJump` serves my purpose — although I still to have to work around my keys setup.

```
ssh -q -J user1@jumphost1,user2@jumphost2,user3@jumphost3 user@server
```

Answer (score 36):

### use a simple `ssh` config file

The `nc` version is not recommended with newer versions of `ssh`.
Instead use the `-W` switch from more recent versions of OpenSSH.
Also, you don't need to copy the config to other hosts!
All of the config needs to be done on your host and it does not interfere with the `scp` in any way.

Here is an example `~/.ssh/config` file for your given example:

```
Host jumphost1
    User username1
Host jumphost2
    User username2
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost1
Host jumphost3
    User username3
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost2
Host server
    User username4
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost3
```

### finally: connect using `ssh server` or `scp file server:path/` or `rsync`.

---

p.s.

For those of you who prefer a drawing instead of text in a ssh config file, here is a signal flow diagram:

```
localhost
        ||
        \/
username1@jumphost1
        ||
        \/
username2@jumphost2
        ||
        \/
username3@jumphost3
        ||
        \/
username4@server
```

---

p.p.s. for fun here is a oneline but please note this approach is hard to type and hard to read:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand= \
  'ssh -W %h:%p -oProxyCommand= \
    \'ssh -W %h:%p -oProxyCommand= \
      \\\'ssh -W %h:%p username1@jumphost1\\\' \
    username2@jumphost2\' \
  username3@jumphost3' \
username4@server
```

You basically need to go from inside.

Comment: Thanks. Tried the one-liner, didn't work. I don't know if it's only the escaping. Can you double-check, please? Also, can you explain why nesting is necessary and chaining doesn't work?

Comment: Well, What does "does not work!" mean? Chaining works, but not with `scp`, because SCP is expecting SCP control messages, but instead gets SSH control messages and fails. On the other hand, the `ProxyCommand` does it transparently and therefore the outermost `ssh` (or `scp`) will get the messages directly from the other end.

Comment: I get the `> ` prompt where is waiting to break the line continuation, I guess — ie, the command never executes.

Comment: I got it to run with double quotes but it's not working. I added a log for `ProxyCommand` and the `ProxyJump` option to my post. I also read about [Old Methods of Passing Through Jump Hosts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Old_Methods_of_Passing_Through_Jump_Hosts) and there's not mention nor example of nested `ProxyCommand` at runtime.

Comment: The problem with the example is that this is not how embedded single quotes work.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/1099103 .  Replacing \' with '"'"' (see link) made it work for me.  I only tried 2 jumphosts though.  I'm not sure how you could do a 3rd jumphost.

Comment: @senorsmile thank you for the comment and feel free to propose edit to this answer that worked for you.

Comment: re "the nc version is not recommended anymore": why isn't "the nc version" recommended anymore?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Because it requires you to have some external program (nc) installed on all the proxy hosts. The IO redirect using -W does not need that and only requirement is to have openssh client installed on your computer.

Comment: @Jakuje thanks for answering the question. less dependencies is always better.

Comment: @Jakuje how do you make escaping of the %h:%p expansion? What I see when I use `ssh -vvv` is that even for my nested commands the `-W %h:%p` expands to the target `host:port`

Comment: @RomanDodin double `%` should work: `%%h` in your case

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje

for the sake of completeness, I provide the full command here for the `src->jmp1->jmp2->dev` path, where the command is issued on `src` and the target machine is `dev`

`ssh -o "ProxyCommand=ssh -W %h:%p -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -W %%h:%%p  root@jmp1' root@jmp2" admin@dev`

Comment: Next step would be: `ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -oProxyCommand=\"ssh -W %%h:%%p -oProxyCommand=\\\"ssh -W %%h:%%p root@jmp1\\\" root@jmp2 \" root@jmp3" root@jmp4`.

Comment: @RomanDodin The double percent character `%%h` does work - I'm curious is this a general escape? (google'd the topic briefly without much success)

Answer (score -1):

I have done this with *two* hops, but it should work for three.  The simplest way is to have the `~/.ssh/config` file set on each host.  So, if you want to be on `hosta` and get to `hostd` via `hostb` and hostc`, you could set your configurations thusly:

In `hosta:~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host hostd
    User username
    ProxyCommand ssh hostb nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

In `hostb:~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host hostd
    User username
    ProxyCommand ssh hostc nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

In `hostc:~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host hostd
    User username
    ProxyCommand ssh hostd nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

You can then `ssh hostd` on any of the hosts in the chain and you'll make your way to `hostd`.

Using netcat for the proxy does not interfere with `scp`.

If for some reason you really don't want to use local `~/.ssh/config` files, you can do this on `hosta`:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand='ssh -oProxyCommand=\'ssh -o ProxyCommand=\\\'ssh username@hostd nc %h %p 2>/dev/null\\\' username@hostc nc %h %p 2> /dev/null' username@hostb nc %h %p 2> /dev/null' username@hostd
```

Comment: As I said, I'm aware of `nc`'s use. Can you actually rewrite the command I posted with `ProxyCommand` as an option?

Comment: You mention "you're aware of its use but want to use `scp`".  It doesn't interfere with `scp`.  But I will give you the comically long command as an edit shortly.

Comment: Thanks. Could you just rewrite your answer focusing on `ProxyCommand` nesting? If you reread my post you'll see that's the gist. I thought I could, instead of nesting like you did, chain all the middle nodes in `ProxyCommand`. I still wonder if that's somehow possible.

Comment: That is in fact what is being done; it's just a lot harder to read than _in situ_ configurations because of all the nested (and increasingly escaped) quotes.  You have to do it that way because you are carrying all of the `ProxyCommand` directives along with you to the next host in the chain.

Comment: This is wrong. The configuration is only on your local computer, not distributed among the hosts on the way as you try to propose.

Comment: "wrong" is, in my opinion, a stronger word than perhaps you should use.  You _can_ put the entire proxy chain on the local machine but, as mentioned, you then have to deal with increasingly deep chains of properly-escaped quotes in the local configuration.  Distributing the links in the chain also means that you can `ssh` to the endpoint from any link in the chain, amongst other arguable benefits.

Comment: Certainly I have no idea why you have on `hostc` the jump to `hostd` through the `hostd` again. Also, if the `hostb` does not see the `hostd`, the `nc` will fail for you in the first jump.